# Not understanding route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I took an AngularJS lesson. But Angular is not understanding links to the details page, like template/1 if I click on a link from the browser. However, if I enter the URL in the address bar of the browser it works fine. How can I resolve this?

**App.js**

```
angular.module('templateStore.templates', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/templates', {
           templateUrl: 'templates/templates.html',
           controller: 'TemplatesCtrl'
     })
    .when('/template/:templateId', {
         templateUrl: 'templates/template-details.html',
         controller: 'TemplateDetailsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/templates'
    });    
}])
.controller('TemplatesCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   console.log('This is Template ');
}])
.controller('TemplateDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     console.log('This is Template Details');
}])
.controller('TemplateDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
     console.log('This is Template Details');
}]);
```

**Templates.html(main page)**

```
<div class="col-md-4 template">
    <h3>Template 4</h3>
    <img src="img/4.jpg">
    <h4>$29.99</h4>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block" href="#/template/1">Details</a>       
</div>
```

[Attached is the image in which I highlighted the url in the address bar after clicking it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIyRe.png)

Comment: Do you need the `#` in `href="#/template/1"`?

Comment: Well, then try to remove it and see. You sometimes have to go with trials and errors, especially if you are trying out something new

Comment: I don't know. I simply followed a tutorial. Without the # or #! it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you use a directive for the templates?

Answer (score 0):

```
.when('/template/:templateId', {
             templateUrl: 'templates/template-details.html',
              controller: 'TemplateDetailsCtrl'
             })  

 App.controller('TemplateDetailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
'$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {        
     console.log($routeParams.templateId); }]);
```

Demo
 Yes you need #/template/2 and above its working code.
may this help you....

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work. When I clicked on the link to the details page, this is the new url that shows in the address bar: templates#%2Ftemplate%2F1. I think angular is not reading or understanding the route.